# React add Component as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a simple problem to solve. I've created a react app using `npx create-react-app`. I made a Map component, which I add to my view with this:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
                </header>
                <p className="App-intro">
                    To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <Map />
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And the Map component appears. Now I want to have a button which has an `onClick` method which calls `Map.addImage`. First of all it cannot be static (addImage uses `Map` members, which have to be initialized in constructor). The problem is I know I would have to do `var map = new Map()`. And then `<button type="button" onClick={map.addImage} />` but how can I make my map appear? I cannot go for:

```
<p>
    <map />
</p>
```

So the question is how can I make my `map` (after `var map = new Map()` in `render()` method, above the return) appear on the screen?

@Edit

`Map` implementation:

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.stage = null;
        this.layer = null;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        //const tween = null;

        this.stage = new Konva.Stage({
            container: this.containerRef,
            width: 1024,
            height: 600
        });


        this.layer = new Konva.Layer();
        //const dragLayer = new Konva.Layer();

        this.stage.add(this.layer);

        /*stage.on("dragstart", function (evt) {
            const shape = evt.target;
            // moving to another layer will improve dragging performance
            shape.moveTo(dragLayer);
            stage.draw();

            if (tween) {
                tween.pause();
            }
            shape.setAttrs({
                shadowOffset: {
                    x: 15,
                    y: 15
                },
                scale: {
                    x: shape.getAttr("startScale") * 1.2,
                    y: shape.getAttr("startScale") * 1.2
                }
            });
        });

        stage.on("dragend", function (evt) {
            const shape = evt.target;
            shape.moveTo(layer);
            stage.draw();
            shape.to({
                duration: 0.5,
                easing: Konva.Easings.ElasticEaseOut,
                scaleX: shape.getAttr("startScale"),
                scaleY: shape.getAttr("startScale"),
                shadowOffsetX: 5,
                shadowOffsetY: 5
            });
        });*/
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                className="container"
                ref={ref => {
                    console.log(ref);
                    this.containerRef = ref;
                }}
            />
        );
    }

    addImage() {
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src = './box.png';
        imageObj.misc = { stage: this.stage, layer: this.layer };
        console.log(this.stage)
        imageObj.onload = function () {
            var image = new Konva.Image({
                x: Math.random() * this.misc.stage.getWidth(),
                y: Math.random() * this.misc.stage.getHeight(),
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                image: imageObj,
                draggable: true
            });
            this.misc.layer.add(image);
            this.misc.layer.draw();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `{map}`?

Comment: You can do `{map}` to render a variable.

Comment: You shouldnt, 

You should move the function
to a higher level and pass it to Map.
You also should not use new Image, you are actually creating a new NON react-node,which is created within the actualy DOM. React cannot keep track of this element with its diff algorithm. you can simply use <img src="./box.png" onload={}>.

Answer (score 0):

As Oblosys said, you generally don't want to try to do this in React. If you must, go with the `ref` route. It's there for a reason.

But I would suggest considering lifting the images up to your `App` state and passing them down as props. It's hard to say what this would look like as you have not provided an implementation for the `Map` component, but it would look *something* like this.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { images: [] };
    this.addImage = this.addImage.bind(this);
  }

  addImage() {
    const newImage = 5; // I obviously have no idea what this actually looks like
    this.setState(({ images }) => ({ images: [...images, newImage] }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <header className="App-header">
           <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
           <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
         </header>
         <p className="App-intro">
           To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
         </p>
         <p>
           <Map images={this.state.images} />
         </p>
         <button onClick={this.addImage}>Add an image</button>
       </div>
     );
  }
}
```

This won't work well in all cases (for example, if you're using a third party tool in `Map`), but this is more The React Way.